# Get object from database or local storage in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have the function getProductById which checks if the product exists in local storage and if not goes to the database:

```
Future<Product> getProductById(String productId) async {
  try {
    // First, try to get the product locally
    Product? product = await localProductManager.getProductByIdFromLocal(productId);
    if (product != null) {
      return product;
    }

    // If not found locally, continue with the existing logic
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user == null) {
      print("User not authenticated");
      throw Exception("User not authenticated");
    }
    return await getProductByIdWithUserId(productId, user.uid);
  } catch (error) {
    print("Error in getProductById: $error");
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Here's the function in LocalProductManager:

```
Future<Product?> getProductByIdFromLocal(String productId) async {
  await _loadViewedProducts();
  if (_viewedProductMap.containsKey(productId)) {
    Map<String, dynamic> productData = _viewedProductMap[productId]!['product'];
    return Product(
      id: productId,
      name: productData['name'] ?? '',
      manufacturer: productData['manufacturer'] ?? '',
      imageUrl: productData['imageUrl'] ?? '',
      badAttributes: Map<String, int>.from(productData['badAttributes'] ?? {}),
      goodAttributes: Map<String, int>.from(productData['goodAttributes'] ?? {}),
      category: productData['category'],
      kosher: productData['kosher'],
      fruitsVeggies: productData['fruitsVeggies'],
      nutsPercentage: productData['nuts'],
      isOrganic: productData['isOrganic'],
      ingredients: List<String>.from(productData['ingredients'] ?? []),
      nutritionalInfo: Map<String, double>.from(productData['nutritionalInfo'] ?? {}),
      servingSize: productData['servingSize'],
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```

When I call the product in my view I get the error:

```
I/flutter (24467): Error in getProductById: Bad state: Future already completed
```

Here's how I load the product in my view:

```
class ProductDetailsView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String barcodeValue;
  final ScrollController? scrollController;

  ProductDetailsView({
    required this.barcodeValue,
    this.scrollController,
  });

  @override
  _ProductDetailsViewState createState() => _ProductDetailsViewState();
}

class _ProductDetailsViewState extends State<ProductDetailsView> {
  late Future<Product?> _productFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadProduct();
  }

  Future<void> _loadProduct() async {
    _productFuture = getProductById(widget.barcodeValue);
  }
  void _showFullScreenImage(String imageUrl) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => FullScreenImage(imageUrl: imageUrl),
      ),
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Product?>(
      future: _productFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text(
              'Product not found',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
        Product product = snapshot.data!;
// Rest of the UI
```

The error "Bad state: Future already completed" typically arises when there's an attempt to complete or modify a Future that has already been completed. This is a concurrency issue. How can I fix this?